# Any option to change the name of the file which is on disk during runtime to execute upload functionality in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario where one of the test REST API returns a transaction_Id, this transaction Id I need to pass in my next request(API Request), also upload the file as well. This upload file has name format like ${transaction_Id}_1_1_bkg.raw,without correct format backend server may not be able to analyze the data.
Since I have to run a load test, these transaction Ids  will generate at run time and the same I have to change the file name and upload it as well.

Did any one had face this challenge before in Jmeter to change the file name at run time and upload it, if yes, what was the solution.

Thanks,
Akshat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the file to a new one with the desired name using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) like

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(new File('template_bkg.raw'), new File(vars.get('transaction_Id') + '_1_1_bkg.raw'))
```

where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for more information on all existing functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article to learn more about JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.

Once upload is finished you can delete the file using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, it is working, thanks for providing solution and idea as well, just small change so that if others get stuck  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(Source file, desired name of file). Also, we can run multiple users as well correct?